# People Search not working after adding query

Tags: 2010, people-search, refinement-panel

I am creating a scoped people search page only for IT department. Yes I do get people refined only from IT department in people search web-part but however then the refinement panel does not filter results. This is the only problem I have. I added query in Result Query Options as shown in below image to get people only from IT department. The refinement panel works perfect when I remove the **Department:"Information Technology"** scope from the Query text-box. Even if I interchange values of Fixed Keyword Query and Append Text to Query still the result is same.

I want the refinement panel to work even with these scoped conditions. Has anyone face a problem like this before? I cannot find solution even after searching on web.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I cracked it! The solution to the above problem was to leave the **Fixed Keyword Query** textbox blank and only write values into **Append Text to Query** textbox. Because if you write a value in **Fixed Keyword Query** then it will only show fixed query results ignoring the Refinement Panel and Search Box. The key is to write values into **Append Text to Query** textbox.

I wrote the value as `contentclass:spspeople DepartmentRefinement:"Information Technology"` inside **Append Text to Query** textbox and the refinement panel worked as expected, filtering all the people search results. Note: Here the **DepartmentRefinement** is my own created Custom Managed Property mapped to **People:Department(Text)** property.

Note: You can combine multiple values in **Append Text to Query** textbox separating the values with a space as I have done.